# Difference between dates and today

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between a given date-range and the date-range of today and a given end-date. the end-result should be at the first step something like: 63% of 3400 hours are already spent. Okay, therefore I tried to do the follwing:

```
//A_diffference between given dates
var t1 = new Date(2015, 1, 13, 13, 20, 0, 0);
var t2 = new Date(2015, 2, 27, 13, 20, 0, 0);
var dif = t2.getTime() - t1.getTime();
var gesamt = Math.abs(dif / 3600000); 
    //B_Difference between today and given date
var jetzt = new Date();
var dif2 = t2.getTime() - jetzt.getTime();
var noch = Math.abs(dif2 / 3600000); 
//C_Difference between the 2
    var bereits = gesamt - noch;
var prozent = (bereits/gesamt)*100;
```

But something within my B-block must be wrong as I am always getting more hours as a result from there, then it should really be.

Could someone tell me what, and maybe hint me how to make the thing a bit more elegant?

As I want to use the calculated percentag later on as a width for a markup-element, I'd like to periodically call that query and thereby update my elements' width which I would do something like that:

```
proz=prozent+"%"; .ready(function(){$(".foo").css({width:"proz"})});
```

Would that be correct? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what `bereits = gesamt - noch` is supposed to represent. Why are you subtracting differences?

Comment: What dates are `t1` and `t2` supposed to be? Is today supposed to be in that range? it's not, because those dates are `Feb 13` and `March 27`. Javascript months start at 0 = January

Comment: What dates do you think t1 and t2 are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you need a function like this:

```
function spentTime(startDate, endDate){
   var sd = startDate.getTime(), sf = Math.abs(new Date().getTime()-sd);
   return {percent:(Math.abs(sd-endDate.getTime())/sf)*100, total_hours:sf/3600000};
}

var spent = spentTime(new Date(2015, 1, 13, 13, 20, 0, 0), new Date(2015, 2, 27, 13, 20, 0, 0));
console.log(spent.percent);
console.log(spent.total_hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want sane datetime management in Javascript you will eventually probably resolve to [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```js
 var t1 = moment('2015-01-13T13:20Z');
 var t2 = moment('2015-02-27T13:20Z');
 var difference = t2.diff(t1, 'days');

 var d = document.createElement("span");
 d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('start: ' + t1.format("DD MMMM YYYY") + '; '));
 d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('end: ' + t2.format("DD MMMM YYYY") + '; '));
 d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('difference: ' + difference + ' days'));
 document.body.appendChild(d);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can pass different parameters to `.diff()`, you can get it in any unit from milliseconds to years, just see [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

as reference from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), month on Date constructor are start from 0 to 11

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

so on your example `t1` will result `Feb 13` and `t2` is `Mar 27`

if you get different from `t2 - now` which is `Jan 17` so it will become more hour than result from `t2 - t1`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) to manipulate dates? I'm a little confused about what you need to do specifically. But with Moment, you can do things like:

```
moment().add(7, 'days').subtract(1, 'months').year(2009).hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0);
```